# Compilation issue with instantiating function template

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, variadic-templates, function-templates

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct S {
  void f(const char* s) {
    std::cout << s << '\n';
  }
};

template <typename... Args, void(S::*mem_fn)(Args...)>
void invoke(S* pd, Args... args) {
  (pd->*mem_fn)(args...);
}

int main() {
  S s;
  void(*pfn)(S*, const char*) = invoke<const char*, &S::f>;
  pfn(&s, "hello");
}
```

When compiling the code, clang gives the following error:

```
main.cpp:16:33: error: address of overloaded function 'invoke' does not match required type 'void (S *, const char *)'
  void(*pfn)(S*, const char*) = invoke<const char*, &S::f>
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:10:6: note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'Args'
void invoke(S* pd, Args... args) {
     ^
1 error generated.
```

The message seems to suggest that the template instantiation `invoke<const char*, &S::f>` has failed. Could somebody give me some clues as to why is this? I believe it has something to do with the parameter pack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is ill-formed. `mem_fn` is in a non-deduced context according to [temp.deduct.type]:

> The non-deduced contexts are:
>     — ...
>     — A function parameter pack that does not occur at the end of the *parameter-declaration-list*.

And from [temp.param]:

> A template parameter pack of a function template **shall not** be followed
>   by another template parameter **unless that template parameter can be deduced** from the *parameter-type-list*
>   of the function template or has a default argument (14.8.2). *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> template<class T1 = int, class T2> class B; // error
>
> // U can be neither deduced from the parameter-type-list nor specified
> template<class... T, class... U> void f() { } // error
> template<class... T, class U> void g() { } // error
> ```
>
> *—end example ]*

The `mem_fn` argument in this declaration:

```
template <typename... Args, void(S::*mem_fn)(Args...)>
void invoke(S* pd, Args... args) {
```

follows a template parameter pack. It cannot be deduced from the list. You could, however, pass it as an argument:

```
template <typename... Args>
void invoke(S* pd, void(S::*mem_fn)(Args...), Args... args);
```

Or wrap the whole thing in a struct so that you don't need to follow a parameter pack with another template:

```
template <typename... Args>
struct Invoke {
    template <void (S::*mem_fn)(Args...)>
    static void invoke(S* pd, Args... args);
};

void(*pfn)(S*, const char*) = Invoke<const char*>::invoke<&S::f>;
```

Comment: Why it cannot be deduced given that `Args` has been explicitly specified?

Comment: OK. I seem to get it. The value of `mem_fn` is explicitly specified rather than deduced from `Args` that precedes it.

Comment: @Lingxi It cannot be deduced quite simply because it's a non-deduced context. The standard simply takes a conservative approach to handling parameter packs.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly more generic alternative to Barry's solution could use `decltype` to deduce the entire member function signature, including the class it belongs to:

```
template <typename Sig, Sig Fn>
struct invoke;

template <typename Ret, class Class, typename... Args, Ret(Class::*mem_fn)(Args...)>
struct invoke <Ret(Class::*)(Args...), mem_fn>
{
    static void exec (Class* pd, Args... args)
    {
        (pd->*mem_fn)(args...);
    }
};
```

Then use it like this:

```
void(*pfn)(S*, const char*) = invoke<decltype(&S::f),&S::f>::exec;
```